# Prevent concurrent cron jobs in pg-boss

Tags: cron

I’m considering pg-boss for running and distributing event-based jobs between the instances of the same service. One of my use cases, apart from event-based, is scheduled jobs. Some of them can take a while and continue running until it’s time to trigger the next invocation - e.g. a job is set to run every 5 minutes but it can take e.g. 8 to complete. In such case I need the system to realize that the previous run is still in progress and not trigger the same job while the previous invocation of it is still in progress, using the example of every 5 minutes and a job taking 8 minutes - I’d like sth like the following to happen:

- 13:00 job triggered
- 13:05 job still runs, system sees it and doesn’t trigger once more even though it’s time
- 13:08 job done
- 13:10 next job run triggered

Is there an elegant way to achieve it with pg-boss without implementing my own locking mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely use singletonKey for this usage.

If you give a singletonKey to a job, only one job will be allowed to be either created or active. And once the job is completed, you can create another job with the same singletonKey.

So basically every 5 minutes you could try to create a job with the same singletonKey. And if the previous one was not completed, then it will not be created.

```
boss.send('my_queue', {foo: 'bar'}, {singletonKey: 'my_unique_key'});
```